# Do any languages implement retained generics on functions passed as parameters?

Tags: generics, types, functional-programming, f#, language-design

Ran across this in F# today:

```
let test<'a> (f: 'a -> unit) =
    let x = f 123
    let y = f "wow"
    ()
```

Which produces a compiler error, since the generic parameter must be the same within each call of test<'a> as described here:
[Type inference not working when passing map function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45563047/type-inference-not-working-when-passing-map-function/45567508#45567508)

While this makes sense, it made me curious if there are any other languages out there that have implemented something like this--maybe a sort of "parameter-level generics"?

As a follow up, what are the challenges to implementing something like this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generic higher order function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7213599/generic-higher-order-function)

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate, especially since that question has only been answered by using workarounds involving inline and interface/class members. I am asking about if there are any languages that implement this sort of thing for first class functions and what challenges a feature like this pose for language development, not why it doesn't work, which I already understood from reading the answer I linked above.

Comment: Instead of a function parameter, you can pass a non-generic interface that has a generic method.

Comment: @ckemper fair enough!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure.  In [Haskell](https://wiki.haskell.org/Rank-N_types), such things are called "higher rank types": they are types in which you are allowed to "move quantification inside parentheses":

```
test :: (forall a. a -> ()) -> ()
test f = let x = f 123
             y = f "wow"
         in ()
```

The "challenge" is also described in the link given:

> Rank-N type reconstruction is undecidable in general, and some
>   explicit type annotations are required in their presence.

Just rank-2 types are decidable, though, AFAIK (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7651410/1346276)).  That's why there are two different flags for enabling them in GHC.

Comment: Cool! I like how they use a feature reminiscent of formal mathematics here, interesting stuff.

Comment: Type theory is pretty much formal mathematics realized in the form of programs :)

Answer (score 1):

One could also claim C++ supports this with it's weird but quite powerful take on parametric polymorphism.

```
template<typename T>
void test(T f)
{
  std::cout << f(123)   << std::endl;
  std::cout << f("wow") << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  test([](auto const & v) 
    { 
      // Note: This is a compile-time test
      if (std::is_same_v<int, std::decay_t<decltype(v)>>)
      {
        return 0;
      }
      else
      {
        return 1;
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: Interesting to see how C++ approaches this!